# Why Scalar Subquery Expressions in the following queries did not violate rules?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, case, scalar-subquery

Oracle says [scalar subqueries are not valid expressions in the following places:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions010.htm)

- In WHEN conditions of CASE expressions
- In GROUP BY and HAVING clauses

But why the following queries don't give any error.(Don't go to the purpose,I am just trying some random examples)

```
select case when (select id from employee where id=60)=60 then 1 end if from employee; 

select id from employee group by id having (select id from employee where id=60)=60;
```

Let there be only one id with value 60

Comment: Your link is to the 10g documentation, but your question is tagged 11g and, well, the documentation is [different](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions013.htm)

Comment: oh I dint notice that.Thanks